# nmap not showing closed ports

Tags: nmap

When I running the command

```
nmap -p 443 -iL ip.txt
```

It only shows IP addresses with open ports in the output, but does not show IP addresses with closed ports. How can I see the closed ports/IPs.

Comment: When I run the above command (with Nmap version 7.6), the output shows the IPs scanned as well as the port (443), the state (open, closed, filtered, unfiltered, open|filtered, or closed|filtered), and the service (https). With this I can see which IPs have port 443 open as well as which IPs have 443 closed, which sounds like what you are after. What version of Nmap are you running?

Answer (score 2):

There is typically a line that shows something like "Not shown: 1494 closed ports, 496 filtered ports", so in this case it would be "Not shown, 1 closed port"... but you're only searching for one port which gives me the filtered or closed result by that port, so can't say what you're seeing. I tried it with debug on and it gives results like what you're looking for. Try:

nmap -d -d -p 443 -iL ip.txt